# crontab with scrapy and postfix

Tags: cron, scrapy, sendmail, system-administration

I´m newbie with many sysadmin´s tasks, I want to create a crontab for firstly, scrap a web page and save info inside a file and then, send it daily to my personal mail.

- I have created a spider with scrapy and it works fine
- I have installed postfix and I can send the generated file inside the body of the mail

But when I mixed this two tasks in the cron, I have some troubles

- I need sudo for execute scrapy
- I don´t know how is to add the subject of the mail with the command I have used.

I received these mails from the system:

- /bin/sh: 1: scrapy: not found
- sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

And this is the cron (the time for execute it its simply for testing)

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/www/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/se_scrapy/ && sudo scrapy crawl quepeliponen -o cartelera.csv && cat cartelera.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -s, -t | less -#5 -N -S | /usr/lib/sendmail -v myemail@gmail.com
```

I would to like make it in crontab one line and not use a bash script due to my poor knowledge about that

Thanks

**Edited**

Ok... I have searched a litle more and I think I have found the solution...

I have added the route of the scrapy command

```
/usr/local/bin/scrapy
```

and I have created the cron job in the crontab root user with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The only thing I need its send the email with a subject to avoid receive it in spam folder

This is the cron now:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/www/wp-content/plugins/se-plugin-name/se_scrapy/ && rm cartelera.csv && /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl quepeliponen -o cartelera.csv && echo "Subject: Cartelera de mañana" | cat cartelera.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -s, -t | less -#5 -N -S | /usr/lib/sendmail -F sendfrom@gmail.com -t sendto@hotmail.com
```

**Edit 2**

I resolve it using mail and not sendmail

```
0 4 * * * cd /var/www/wp-content/plugins/se-plugin-name/se_scrapy/ && rm cartelera.csv && /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl quepeliponen -o cartelera.csv && cat cartelera.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -s, -t | less -#5 -N -S | mail -aFrom:sender@gmail.com -s "La cartelera de mañana" email1@gmail.com email2@gmail.com
```

Comment: if you solve this by yourself, remember to make it answer

Comment: Ok, I still need to resolve send email with subject. The subject is not sending:

`echo "Subject: Cartelera de mañana" | cat cartelera.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -s, -t | less -#5 -N -S | /usr/lib/sendmail -F sendfrom@gmail.com -t sendto@hotmail.com`

Comment: Ok... I resolve it using mail command... `0 4 * * * cd /var/www/wp-content/plugins/se-plugin-name/se_scrapy/ && rm cartelera.csv && /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl quepeliponen -o cartelera.csv && cat cartelera.csv | sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' | column -s, -t | less -#5 -N -S | mail -aFrom:sender@gmail.com -s "La cartelera de mañana" email1@gmail.com email2@gmail.com`